# $statechangestart event not fired in angularjs with typescript version 1.7.2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

`$stateChangeStart` event not fired in AngularJS with TypeScript version 1.7.2

I got `$transitions` as solution, but can't understand how to inject it in AngularJS with TypeScript. Which library or `npm` module have to add in project, can't understand.

Comment: `$transitions` is part of `ui.router` module, you inject it as any other service (usually in `angular.run`)

Comment: but  function angular_initialize($state: ng.ui.IStateService) this way we follow to inject service, so i can't understand what to do for  $transitions

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44187147/8495123) (`$transitions: TransitionService`)

Comment: get error 'Cannot find name TransitionService'